# What techniques for disk, volume and file system management are possible with OS X, but troublesome within Disk Utility?

Tags: macos, disk-utility, filesystem, core-storage

In the past, Disk Utility was the best starting point for the vast majority of disk-related tasks.

As technologies within (or possible with) OS X have developed – without equal development of Disk Utility – so it may be useful to have:

- a shortlist of actions that are best attempted/begun *without* Disk Utility.

## This question

I'd like answers to form something like:

- a **shortlist** of things that appear **illogical or impossible** in Disk Utility.

I'll seed at least one answer to exemplify what I have in mind.

For some of the things mentioned, there will be answers elsewhere in Stack Exchange – so here, commentary may be minimal.

## Background

Maybe more noticeable with Mountain Lion than with Lion:

1. some capabilities that are integral to the operating system are
   misrepresented or impossible within Disk Utility
2. some capabilities that are added by third part software are misrepresented within Disk Utility

… and so on.

I'm fairly familiar with routines for HFS Plus and for ZEVO implementations of ZFS. Less familiar with routines for other file systems (both native and not native to OS X).

Recall that features such as Core Storage and FileVault 2 are relatively new, and without native support in Snow Leopard, so let's be gentle in our observations – for any peculiarity, assume that an overriding mantra of 'first do no harm' is applied by Apple.

### Beyond this question

A redesign of Disk Utility, by Apple, is desirable but that will be [beyond the scope of Ask Different](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5550078#5550078) so please: **no design suggestions here**.

#### Discussion in Ask Different Chat

- [2012-07-28](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5549782#5549782)
- [2012-07-29](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5553375#5553375)

### Additional context (November 2015)

http://forums.macrumors.com/posts/22209602 for a public record of what was originally a private enhancement request (ER), made through AppleSeed in 2012.

Comment: Alongside the close vote: please, can you offer an improvement to the question? I do wish for this question to be [acceptable in the way discussed](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5550078#5550078) with Nathan Greenstein – an **inventory** of *what Disk Utility doesn't support*, if you like.

Comment: Vote to close because I don't see the point of it. Just collecting a list of potential non-features of Disk Utility doesn't provide any value. Collecting a list of features a (any) Disk Utility *should* support would probably be better (at least for someone who wants to build a new one) but is off-topic.

Comment: This question is partly a companion to, more focused than, [What features from Lion will be lost when upgrading to Mountain Lion?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/57455/8546).

Comment: This feels more like the beginning of a blog post than the summary of a problem you face in need of an answer.

Comment: @bmike I agree. I think this really isn't best as a question, but rather a blog post, as you suggested.

Comment: I doubt that I'll get answers to a blog post without Ask Different, but close the question if you think it's not fitting. Maybe I need to reword the question, but I can't get my head around that at the moment …

Comment: Since Disk Utility got a major rewrite in El Capitan, which fixed some of the problems of the old one (can now see devices even when they have Core Storage volumes on them), but also created some new ...gaps... would it make sense to create a new question for the new Disk Utility?

Comment: Chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/25242037#25242037

Answer (score 3):

## Things not within a logical volume group (LVG) appear to be within the LVG

Affected: some applications of Core Storage, including but not limited to FileVault 2 in Mountain Lion.

### Example

Disk Utility 13 (426) in Build 12A269 of OS X 10.8:

[image: A shot of Disk Utility with an LVG containing three things not within the LVG]

Volumes *swap* and *spare* are JHFS+ and truly not within the LVG.

*disk0s3* is an `Apple_Journal`, currently unused and truly not within the LVG.

Disk Utility misrepresents all three as being within the LVG.

Comment: If you clarify those acronyms, about 50 times as many people will be able to understand your post. I'm guessing LVG is "logical volume group"? Is JHFS+ "Mac Extended Journaled" I'm a pretty geeky person, but I'm still uncertain.

Comment: Yes, logical volume group and LVG both in the first line. LVG is the acronym. Thanks for the nudge.

Answer (score 1):

## A physical disk may be invisible

Affected: some applications of Core Storage, including but not limited to FileVault 2 in Mountain Lion.

### S.M.A.R.T. status may be invisible

When Disk Utility can not visualise the disk:

- it is impossible for the utility to present the status.

For users who see this as [a regression in Mountain Lion](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/58288/8546): there are workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

## Management of some types of partitions becomes impossible with the Partition tab

With Lion and Mountain Lion, when the Partition tab of Disk Utility in Lion can not manage a partition on a physical disk that uses Apple Core Storage:

- [ignore the Partition tab](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/59042/8546).

With Mountain Lion, [disappearance of the physical disk](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/58286/8546) – presentation of an LVG in its place – may be an additional source of confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Apple does provide some non-Finder alternatives for advanced users to show items that would otherwise be hidden, or provide extra options:

a) Disk Utility Debug mode (let's you see Recovery Partitions, etc)

```
defaults write com.apple.DiskUtility advanced-image-options -bool true
```

b) the "hdiutil" command-line tool (provides more formats, etc):

```
man hdiutil
```

The majority of users just need to back up, restore disk images and (visible) volumes. I doubt the average user even bothers with software raid or partioning.

I have a feeling none of this info is news to the original poster (and doesn't address the actual question, to be honest), but maybe others will find it helpful.

Comment: True, this is not a perfect fit for the question. However the question is arguably not a good fit with Ask Different – and there's tumbleweed – so I'm grateful for  the attention. Recent attention to Fusion Drive/[DIY](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/69538/8546) (and who knows what's to come from Apple?) might encourage broader thinking about what can not be done with Disk Utility.