# How to install Mountain Lion on a disk that cannot be formatted in recovery mode?

Tags: macos, upgrade, disk-utility

I'm trying to do a clean install of Mountain Lion but I'm not being able to format my partition.

I previously had Lion, encrypted the disk, then upgraded to Mountain Lion, then booted into recovery mode to format & reinstall Mountain Lion.

On recovery mode (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>), when I tried to format the encrypted partition I got an error saying something like "not enough space on core something". Now the partition doesn't show up on Disk Utility; only the disk, "Macintosh HD", but I am not able to repartition it.

The Mountain Lion installer doesn't find any disk to install itself on.

I cannot boot the system either (without booting to recovery).

If I open the terminal and type `diskutil list` I can see that there's an Apple_CoreStorage on /dev/disk0s2, but I cannot reformat that volume ("The disk is in use by Core Storage as a Physical Volume").

How to format the disk and install Mountain Lion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use `dd` to destroy the partition's header. You can then format (erase) it and run the install.

From the installer run **Terminal** and type the following:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/disk0s2 bs=1024 count=1024
```

Do be warned, this will irrecoverably destroy all data on that partition. But it looks like that's what you're expecting. Make sure you don't accidentally target the wrong thing.

Also note that I haven't done this, exactly. I've used this technique to destroy the *entire partition table*, not just a single partition. But I think it should work.

When you're done quit **Terminal** and run **Disk Utility**. You won't get any complaints about Core Storage.

Comment: This did not work, I still have the exact same issues.

Comment: Is it safe to format the entire /dev/disk0? The volumes EFI and Apple_Boot seem to be important.

Comment: That will also destroy your recovery partition. If you have an external disk to boot from (or a newer Mac that will netboot over the Internet) then yes it's safe. You just need to re-partition afterward.

Comment: Ok, do you have more information about how to recreate those partitions?

Comment: Creating a single partition with Disk Utility will restore everything except the recovery partition. If I understand correctly, the OS install will create the recovery partition.

Comment: Thanks for this. I tried a hundred other solutions with `diskutil` and `diskutil cs`, but none of the operations completed successfully. Zeroing out the volume with `dd` was the only way to nuke it sufficiently to be able to reformat it as a non-fusion drive.

Answer (score 2):

When the Partition tab of Disk Utility in Mountain Lion can not manage a partition on a physical disk that uses Apple Core Storage:

## Ignore the Partition tab

Instead of selecting the logical volume group (to the left):

- select the encrypted logical partition (to the right of, and below, the LVG)
- use the Erase tab.

---

[What techniques for disk, volume and file system management are possible with OS X, but troublesome within Disk Utility?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/58283/8546)

In particular:

- [a physical disk may be invisible](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/58286/8546).

Answer (score 1):

Without destroying all partitions/slices of the physical disk:

## Use the coreStorage verb of [diskutil](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/darwin/reference/manpages/man8/diskutil.8.html)

To delete the logical volume group that is no longer required:

1. get the UUID of the group
2. run a command based on the following format:

`diskutil coreStorage delete lvgUUID`

If a logical volume within the group is mounted, it may be necessary to unmount before attempting destruction. Also maybe necessary to use `sudo` … sorry I can't be more specific, it's a couple of weeks or so since I last performed an action of this type .

Comment: I'll have to try this.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this solution:

[OS X Mountain Lion “clean” install gotcha: CoreStorage / Encrypted Disk issue](http://www.drake.org.uk/2012/07/os-x-mountain-lion-clean-install-gotcha-corestorage-encrypted-disk-issue/)

Basically, you need to run `diskutil CoreStorage list` from Terminal. Identify the logical CoreStorage volume from that list and note the UUID string.

Then type `diskutil CoreStorage delete UUID` where *UUID* is the string you identified.

You can then partition with Disk Utility and run a Mountain Lion install.