# For a startup volume encrypted with Core Storage, System Preferences show that FileVault is disabled

Tags: macos, terminal, disk-utility, filevault, recovery

My iMac has a SSD and a HDD. The OS is installed on the SSD.

I performed a clean installation of Mountain Lion to the SSD, and cloned my SSD using a backup from my Time Capsule in [OS X Recovery](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4718).

System Preferences show that FileVault is not enabled.

When I follow the routine to enable FileVault, after the iMac reboots it gives me the following error:

> **There was a problem enabling FileVault.**
>   Problems were encountered with the disk “Crucial M4 SSD”. Please turn off FileVault, verify and (if necessary) repair the disk with Disk Utility, and try enabling FileVault again.

I have verified and repaired the disks in Disk Utility. I used Disk Utility in OS X Recovery. Here I was unable to unlock the volume on the SSD with Disk Utility, so instead I used Terminal to unlock the volume. After the unlocked volume appeared in Disk Utility I was able to verify and repair the disk, but I still got the above error.

Results in Terminal:

- when trying to decrypt the volume, I am told that that the volume is not encrypted
- when trying to encrypt the volume, I am told that the volume is already encrypted

– very confusing :)

```
Denniss-iMac:~ dennis$ diskutil coreStorage decryptVolume 4FDED44E-EC4B-4B11-9FF5-9C958BD8CEAB
Passphrase:
Error beginning CoreStorage Logical Volume decryption: The target Core Storage volume is not encrypted (-69755)
```

-

```
Denniss-iMac:~ dennis$ diskutil coreStorage encryptVolume 4FDED44E-EC4B-4B11-9FF5-9C958BD8CEAB
New passphrase for existing volume:
Confirm new passphrase:
Started CoreStorage operation on disk2 Crucial M4 SSD
Error: -69696: The target Core Storage volume is already encrypted
```

## Questions

How can I enable FileVault on my iMac?

Is there a way to reset the partition without having to reinstall and reconfigure my system?

### coreStorage world

```
Denniss-iMac:~ dennis$ diskutil coreStorage list
CoreStorage logical volume groups (2 found)
|
+-- Logical Volume Group 52C795EE-D034-4F54-9691-EF6D04AD5FF9
|   =========================================================
|   Name:         Crucial M4 SSD
|   Size:         255200755712 B (255.2 GB)
|   Free Space:   16777216 B (16.8 MB)
|   |
|   +-< Physical Volume AB27C53B-03C1-481D-9E02-B21DA84AE0F4
|   |   ----------------------------------------------------
|   |   Index:    0
|   |   Disk:     disk0s2
|   |   Status:   Online
|   |   Size:     255200755712 B (255.2 GB)
|   |
|   +-> Logical Volume Family BB92E15C-2063-4F56-99EB-5AD588AECDBB
|       ----------------------------------------------------------
|       Encryption Status:       Unlocked
|       Encryption Type:         None
|       Conversion Status:       Failed
|       Conversion Direction:    backward
|       Has Encrypted Extents:   Yes
|       Fully Secure:            No
|       Passphrase Required:     No
|       |
|       +-> Logical Volume 4FDED44E-EC4B-4B11-9FF5-9C958BD8CEAB
|           ---------------------------------------------------
|           Disk:               disk2
|           Status:             Online
|           Size (Total):       254865207296 B (254.9 GB)
|           Size (Converted):   -none-
|           Revertible:         Yes (unlock and decryption required)
|           LV Name:            Crucial M4 SSD
|           Volume Name:        Crucial M4 SSD
|           Content Hint:       Apple_HFS
|
+-- Logical Volume Group F0D53CC0-68D7-44FA-B2F9-0874A4FD181D
    =========================================================
    Name:         Storage
    Size:         999860912128 B (999.9 GB)
    Free Space:   0 B (0 B)
    |
    +-< Physical Volume BFD4B09C-0CE5-40B4-BB3D-9C7E96589573
    |   ----------------------------------------------------
    |   Index:    0
    |   Disk:     disk1s2
    |   Status:   Online
    |   Size:     999860912128 B (999.9 GB)
    |
    +-> Logical Volume Family B86F5A3A-C642-4956-8D21-B724CFDC3028
        ----------------------------------------------------------
        Encryption Status:       Unlocked
        Encryption Type:         AES-XTS
        Conversion Status:       NoConversion
        Conversion Direction:    -none-
        Has Encrypted Extents:   Yes
        Fully Secure:            Yes
        Passphrase Required:     Yes
        |
        +-> Logical Volume 97EDE534-A8B0-494B-8D1F-C79D136C8327
            ---------------------------------------------------
            Disk:               disk3
            Status:             Online
            Size (Total):       999709908992 B (999.7 GB)
            Size (Converted):   -none-
            Revertible:         No
            LV Name:            Storage
            Volume Name:        Storage
            Content Hint:       Apple_HFS
```

Similar reports of problems:

- ["There was a problem enabling FileVault." Error Message.](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4164616)
- [FileVault won't encrypt a previously decrypted system volume.](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4152801)

A screenshot of the errors when I try to enable FileValut:
[image: FileVault Errors]

Comment: Boot into single user mode and run `fsck -f` and tell us what the results are.

Comment: After `fsck` has been checking multiple items, the result is `The volume Crucial M4 SSD appears to be OK`.

Comment: Have you by any chance cloned the SSD from your previous computer using something like SuperDuper?

Comment: No, I "cloned" my SSD using a backup from my *Time Capsule* in the *OS X Recovery*.

Answer (score 2):

## Suggestions

### Review System Preferences

Create another user.

Log in as that user.

Use the Security & Privacy pane of System Preferences. In the FileVault tab, click **Enable Users…** then in the sheet, ensure that all required users are enabled.

#### Hint

System Preferences may show that FileVault is enabled, with a recovery key, when there is encryption with Core Storage, but neither FileVault 2 nor a recovery key.  I reported this bug to Apple a while ago.

Similarly, but not the same bug:

- I assume that System Preferences may show FileVault *disabled* on a system where most elements of FileVault *are* enabled.

### Thorough application of Disk Utility

Ensure that the utility is applied:

- to the logical volume **group**, which appears to contain the logical volume.

(Where Core Storage is used, [Disk Utility in 10.8 can not show the physical disk](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/58286/8546).)

If you select the LV alone, then verification will omit the partition map.

## Observations

> Conversion Status:    Failed

If encryption was applied when the volume was created (typically: erasure with Disk Utility) then:

- there was no conversion forward
- conversion backward can not begin.

> Conversion Direction:    backward

This implies that:

- recently, conversion backward did begin
- previously, the logical volume was the result of conversion forward (not the result of erasure with Disk Utility).

> `diskutil coreStorage encryptVolume 4FDED44E-EC4B-4B11-9FF5-9C958BD8CEAB`

That could apply if logical volume 4FDED44E-EC4B-4B11-9FF5-9C958BD8CEAB was **not** encrypted.

As the LV is already encrypted, the response from `diskutil` is correct.

### The question in Apple Support Communities

From the opening poster:

- [Cannot enable FileVault](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4189084)

Does the resolution there in ASC, the bounty here in Ask Different, mean that Dennis continues to seek a more detailed answer, a better resolution?

### Code -69755

-69755 appears in another discussion:

- [FileVault failed and now I can't turn it off.](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3197792)

### Interpreting the failure

Pessimistically but realistically:

- a failure to convert – with conversion of nothing – may indicate media failure, possibly in or around the area occupied by the extents file.